# C++ template comprehension

Tags: c++, templates, semantics

I am trying to understand what would be the meaning of the following code since it is a valid C++ code:

```
template<class A>
class AT
{
    AT();
};

template<class B>
AT<B>::AT()
{}
```

Can someone help me understand what is the effect of the template instantiation in the constructor? And also if someone can come with a useful practical use case I would greatly appreciate.

Tanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no template instantiation here. The later half of this code simply defines the constructor for the `AT` class. Note that it general practice to use the same names for the template parameters when doing this:

```
template<class A>
class AT
{
    AT();
};

template<class A>
AT<A>::AT()
{}
```

The use for this syntax would be to break dependency loops:

```
template<class A>
class AT
{
    AT();
};

class Dependent
{
    AT<Dependant> member; // Complete definition of AT is needed here
};

template<class A>
AT<A>::AT()
{
    Dependent object; // Complete definition of Dependent is needed here
}
```

Comment: Ok but what template<class B> mean then?

Comment: That a declaration or definition of a template follows... ?

Answer (score 3):

The name of the template parameter is not important. If you write the second part as

```
template<class A>
AT<A>::AT()
{ }
```

the magic goes away and it is just a definition of the constructor.